# SwiftUI unexpected animations when toggling animations In .onAppear (using a GeometryReader's size)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I have a strange animation behavior in `SwiftUI`. I've tried to create a minimal view that demonstrates it below.

I want to animate in three circles with a fade and a scale effect (see column "What I Expect" below). However, the size of the circles depends on the width of the view, so I'm using a `GeometryReader` to get that.

I want to start the animation in `.onAppear(perform:)`, but at the time that is called, the `GeometryReader` hasn't set the `size` property yet. What I end up with is the animation you see in *"Unwanted Animation 1"*. This is due to the frames being animated from `.zero` to their correct sizes.

However, whenever I try to disable the animations for the frames by adding a `.animation(nil, value: size)` modifier, I get an extremely strange animation behavior (see *"Unwanted Animation 2"*). This I don't understand at all. It somehow adds a horizontal translation to the animation which makes it look even worse. Any ideas what's happening here and how to solve this?

Strangely, everything works fine if I use an explicit animation like this:

```swift
.onAppear {
    withAnimation {
      show.toggle()
    }
}
```

But I want to understand what's going on here.

Thanks!

### Update:

Would replacing `.onAppear(perform:)` with the following code be reasonable? This would trigger only once in the lifetime of the view, right when `size` changes from `.zero` to the correct value.

```swift
.onChange(of: size) { [size] newValue in
    guard size == .zero else { return }
    show.toggle()
}
```

---

| What I Expect | Unwanted Animation 1 | Unwanted Animation 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @State private var show = false
    @State private var size: CGSize = .zero

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            circle
            circle
            circle
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .background {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Color.clear.onAppear { size = proxy.size }
            }
        }
        .onAppear { show.toggle() }
    }

    private var circle: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: circleSize, height: circleSize)
            .animation(nil, value: size) // This make the circles animate in from the side for some reason (see "Strange Animation 2")
            .opacity(show ? 1 : 0)
            .scaleEffect(show ? 1 : 2)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1), value: show)
    }

    private var circleSize: Double {
        size.width * 0.2 // Everything works fine if this is a constant
    }
}


struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The real size is known *after* first layout, but `.onAppear` is called *before*, so layout (including frame change, which is animatable) goes under animation.

To solve this we need to delay state change a bit (until first layout/render finished), like

```
.onAppear {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
        show.toggle()
    }
}
```

... and this is why `withAnimation` also works - it actually delays closure call to next cycle.

Tested with Xcode 13 / iOS 15

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the clarification! Thanks to your answer I had an idea, see the updated question. What do you think about that? The `.onChange` should only ever be called once at the beginning of the view's lifetime. This way, a fixed time delay wouldn't be necessary. Do you see any problem with that approach?

Comment: No, `onChange` will be triggered on every change in parent layout, so animation will restart... but in your specific UI (which is unknown for me) this might not happen ever.

Comment: I might misunderstand something but shouldn’t the guard statement prevent multiple triggers? Or will the size reset to .zero every time a parent view changes layouts?