# ToolbarItem is included in the animation but shouldn't

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I made this cute little animation with just a few lines of code and it works great.
But, for some reason, the "settings" icon from the `ToolbarItem` is included into it whereas it was clearly not my intention.

Here's the problem if you can't run this piece of code: the "settings" icon is "offsetted" at first and then moved to the right position at the same time of the first animation for the second `ZStack`.

Do you have an idea why?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ParentView: View {
    @State private var isTapped = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                ChildView()
                // Content
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button(action: { }, label: {
                        Image("settings")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 28, height: 28)
                    })
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text("Parent View")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @State private var isSowingTwo = false
    @State private var isSowingThr = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                    .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                    .onAppear { animateIcons() }
                Image("car")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
            }
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                    .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                    .overlay(
                        Circle()
                            .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    )
                Image("bike")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
            }
            .padding(.leading, -4)
            .opacity(isSowingTwo ? 1 : 0)
            .offset(x: isSowingTwo ? 0 : 80)
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                    .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                    .overlay(
                        Circle()
                            .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    )
                Image("other")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
            }
            .padding(.leading, -4)
            .opacity(isSowingThr ? 1 : 0)
            .offset(x: isSowingThr ? 0 : 80)
        }
    }

    private func animateIcons() {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut.delay(0.60)) {
            isSowingTwo = true
        }
        withAnimation(.easeInOut.delay(1.20)) {
            isSowingThr = true
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Sruggling to reproduce this problem. Even when images from SF Symbols are used and ParentView is nested inside a ```NavigationStack```, I am not seeing the settings image move in any way. Running on an iPhone 14 simulator (iOS 16.4) with Xcode 14.3.1.

Comment: @BenzyNeez That's interesting, because I quickly reproduced the problem on my machine. I'm using Xcode 14.3, just one version behind, and the iPhone 14 Pro and iPad Pro simulators both reproduced the problem.

Comment: You're right, I totally forgot to add `NavigationStack` and also `(spacing: 0)` to the last `HStack`.

Comment: I'm also on Xcode 14.3 with a physical iPhone 14 (iOS 16.5.1).

Comment: @Sweeper Useful feedback, I see it now with an iPhone 14 Pro simulator! Still don't see it on an iPhone 14 simulator, even with the updated code, but 14 Pro is fine to go on.

Comment: So a symptom of the delayed animations it seems. I (now) even see it when circles 2+3 are completely commented out! The answer/workaround by @Sweeper looks good to me too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a SwiftUI bug, [especially since reportedly this cannot be reproduced on Xcode 14.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76687159/toolbaritem-is-included-in-the-animation-but-shouldnt/76687317#comment135202329_76687159).

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70375090/5133585), which I think is highly related, `onAppear` is called before laying out the views. At that time, it could be the case that the toolbar item is still not positioned correctly (a little bit to the top left). If you inspect the UI hierarchy, the tool bar items seem to be positioned with some sort of `XXXReader` too. Presumably, they can't "read" correctly when the view is not properly laid out yet, like `GeometryReader`.

Then, when the animation is processed, it gets laid out, so its frame changes, and the frame change also gets animated.

Same as that post, a simple way to avoid this is to add the animations a little later:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    withAnimation(.easeInOut.delay(0.60)) {
        isSowingTwo = true
    }
    withAnimation(.easeInOut.delay(1.20)) {
        isSowingThr = true
    }
}
```

Comment: It works very well. I use it like this: .onAppear { DispatchQueue.main.async { animateIcons() } } but it's identical. Thanks!